# How to make params in requests by axios into objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I have this code on a ReactJs app:

```
 axios
      .get(`/shipping/get-shipping-values`, {
        params: {
          products: [
            {
              ...product,
              quantity,
            },
          ],
          postalCode,
          cartTotalPrice: getProductPriceNumber(product.price) * quantity,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        // do things with response
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

This is the console log of the **products param** in the express:

```
[ //Note above the ' that transform this object in an string.
  '{"package":{"weight":0.067,"width":5,"height":2,"length":2},"quantity":945}' 
]
```

Console log of **products** in the **frontend**:

```
[ package: { weight: 0.067, width: 5, height: 2, length: 2}, quantity: 945 ]
```

As you can see, is an array but the object inside this array is an string.

I didn't change the default header of the axios, so is set to aplication/json.

I could use an JSON.parse() to make this string into an object. But I want to know if there is a way to make this automatic. That way I will not need to JSON.parse() every param that I send to the express server.

Comment: Because in the object part has an ' ' and make everything looks like a string.

Comment: oh, yeah, sorry, wasn't looking clearly ... removing my "noisy" comments

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying to help :D

Comment: I could use an JSON.parse(), but this way I will have to use in every route and I just don't know if that is the right way to do. 
I'm transforming an GraphQl app in an RestAPI, so I'm noob in axios requests...

Comment: What’s “product” on the client side? We see the call, we don’t know what data you’re feeding to the call.

Comment: Is an object. Dave, I could solve this using an JSON.parse(). You know if I have to use JSON.parse() in all my params? Is that normal?

Comment: @DaniloCunha No, which is why I'm asking--it'd be more convenient if you showed (in the question) what *specifically* you're sending, e.g., it's suspicious there's no `quantity` in your logged output. As it stands I don't think there's enough information here to help.

Comment: I have edited the question to make more understandable. So as I say, the products is an array of objects in the frontend. But when I send as am param in the axios requests, products become a array of string. I could parse the string to object, but I want to know if there is a way to send a param already parsed.

Comment: If you know a way that I don't need to use JSON.parse() in param sended by axios, please answer this question so I could accept you answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expressJS add `app.use(express.json());` middleware, before the routes and you can find the entire object inside the `req.body` object, inside the route handler.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I have this middleware already, the problem is with params, not the body. You know if I should use JSON.parse() in every param that I receive?

Comment: I could not find any other solution with params. I would send complex objects inside body since I would not have to parse them in the back-end just extract them from  `req.body`